# Do you know best site on Net to learn XHTML 1.0 strict , Like other than W3schools.com but with better and latest content?

Tags: html, xhtml, seo, accessibility, semantic-markup

Do you know best site on Net to learn XHTML , Like other than W3schools.com but with better and latest content?

I have to link some friends who want to learn HTML? I like the "Try it editor" of W3C schools but not the content. I need semantic discussion also. what is the element all about and what is the semantic value, even if's it's valid, should we use or not. etc

Is there any other site focused on Semantic , accessible and Valid XHTML with good content with "try it editor" like w3c schools?

or now i should suggest to someone to learn HTML 5 Directly?

Comment: but wont they still need to know xhtml before html5 since html5 is just a bunch of new tags with additional features?

Comment: @Shawn Mclean - yes but i thought it would be better to provide one resource. which should have all tag supported in HTML 5

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the html section on sitepoint.com They have some good up to date content with a "Play" section.

[Html Section](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html)

[Play Example](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id/demo)